# Optimizing query with huge amount of data in laravel joining two tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get values from two tables storing more than 500K values with the following code in Laravel/ SQL database InnoDB :

```
\DB::table('kw_stats')
->leftJoin('kw_keywords', function($join)
             {
                $join->on('kw_stats.query', '=', 'kw_keywords.query'); 
                $join->on('kw_stats.userID', '=', 'kw_keywords.domainID'); 
            })
->select('kw_stats.query', 'kw_stats.result', 'kw_keywords.sv')
->where('kw_stats.userID',$domain_single->id)
->where('kw_stats.created_at',date("Y-m-d"))
->orderBy('kw_stats.id')->chunk(100, function ($keywords_serps) use (&$progress) {
```

Two tables with these structures:

**kw_keywords:**

```
|--id--query--sv--domainID|
```

**kw_stats:**

```
|--id--query--serpresult--userID |
```

It takes more than 2 minutes for each 100 selected rows.

Is there anyway to optimize the whole process?

Comment: what is the database you use?

Comment: SQL database InnoDB

Comment: Have you tried `DB::select(DB::raw('...'))`, as in writing the query in raw form? From my experience, it helps a lot.